# Stop div from overlapping over nav bar

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, styled-components

I have an App container, which has two components, the nav bar and the content div. Problem now is for some reason, when I resize the window, specifically the height, the content div sneaks up overlapping the nav bar. The smaller the hieght of the window gets, the more it covers of the nav bar.

EDIT:  Just realized that when i remove the content entirely, it still does it??? Like the empty nothingness still goes over the nav bar. So is it the nav bar thats decreasing in height? But if it is, the text is still perfectly placed, how is that so. How's the empty space taking over the nav bar

Main Layout.js

```
// Defining styles
const AppContainer = styled.div`
    box-sizing: border-box;
`;

// Defining styles
const Content = styled.div `
    display:flex;
    min-height: 94vh;
    width: 100vw;
`;


const Container = styled.div `
    background-color: #FAFFEB;
    padding: 15px;
    flex-grow: 12;
    
    `;
    
// -------------
// Nav Bar styles
// ------------
[enter image description here][1]
const NavBar = styled.nav `
    background-color: #f06e6c;
    width: 100vw;
    height:6vh;
`;

const NavList = styled.ul `
    padding: 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    height:6vh;
    margin: 0px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    
`;

const NavItem = styled.li `
    padding: 30px 10px 0px 10px;
    height:6vh;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #FAFFEB;
    text-align: center;

    
    &:hover {
        background: #ff8987;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
`;

const Logo = styled.li `
    padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    height:6vh;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    font-size: 24pt;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #FAFFEB;
    text-align: center;
    
    &:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
`;



function MainLayout({children}) {
    return (
        <AppContainer>
            
            <NavBar>
                <NavList>
                    <Logo>Tasks</Logo>
                    <NavItem>Login</NavItem>
                </NavList>
            </NavBar>
    
            <Content> 
                <SideBar /> 
                <Container>
                    {children}

                </Container>
            </Content>
        </AppContainer>
    )
}

export default MainLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is likely coming from the 'min-height' property; this gives a minimum height but not a maximum, so perhaps this is causing the content div to become larger than 94vh when resizing.

Perhaps a better approach is to have the following styles:

Content div = 'height : 94%'
Nav div = 'height: 6%'.

Let the parent div AppContainer have the styles:
'height:100vh;
width:100vw;'

This way the children divs Content and Nav will always be proportional to their parent.

Comment: Nope, no difference. This is weird. Because yeah as you said, the content height is changing for some reason but its not from the bottom. Its from the top? Cuz like it increases bit by bit until it covers the nav bar which is above it. Even if i put in like height 90%, it crops it from the bottom but still creeps up onto the nav bar

Comment: oh no, just realized that when i remove the content entirely, it still does it??? Like the empty nothingness still goes over the nav bar. So is it the nav bar that decreasing in height? But if it is, the text is still perfectly placed, how is that so

Comment: nvm, realized using 6vh on navbar isnt the smartest idea cuz itll just keep getting smaller and i dont want my navbar to get smaller. So now im just using px. But im having other problem. ffs. We persevere ig

Comment: That's a good idea to have a static width for your navbar, Saif. I'm afraid it's a little bit difficult to imagine what is going wrong from your description (maybe a screenshot would help?). I think that the css is causing it to behave in a way you wouldn't expect. Maybe try experimenting with : removing flex:grow from your container div, or as Yasin says, removing the 'display:flex' property, or maybe fixing the position of the navbar ( 'position:fixed' ) or perhaps bringing the z-index of the navbar forward ( 'z-index: 9999' ).